# is there a way to import csv data into a sqlite db, while not explicitly typing the columns out

Tags: python, sqlite

hoping not to use pandas for this.

```
#create a sqllite database
#step 1: create a connection

import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
sqlcursor = conn.cursor()

###--------------------------------STEP 2: IMPORT GEOSPATIAL DATA--------------------------------###
import csv
geofile = r'geodata.csv'
with open(geofile, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvdata = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(csvdata, None)
    csvrows = []
    for row in csvdata:
        if len(row[0]) < 5:
            row[0] = row[0].zfill(5)
        if len(row[1]) != 2:
            print('state: '+row[1])
        csvrows.append(tuple(row))

sqlcursor.executemany('SELECT * INTO geodata FROM VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?);', csvrows)
conn.commit()
```

obviously this doesn't work, but for example in sql i can do something like this:

```
select * from
(
values
 ('207-544')
,('208-609')
,('208-601')
,('984-520')
,('989-318')
) AS m(combos)
```

so looking to use select into vs insert into, since i dont actually have a table - and don't want to make one beforehand

Comment: You can do this from the `sqlite3` command line, with `.mode csv` and `.import xxx.csv tablename`.  No Python required.

Comment: @TimRoberts well the issue is right now im using the zfill, but i might have to do some other manipulations in the future...

Comment: You're already ignoring the CSV header line.  It would be trivial to create a `CREATE TABLE` statement from that, and then you just need a series of `INSERT INTO` requests.  As long as you're inserting every column, you don't need to specify the column list.  `INSERT INTO geodata VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);`.

Comment: @TimRoberts yep that's what im working with as of now (thats why theres an ignore there), but i figured itd be nice to learn how to make it dynamic.  especially since i have other files with like 30 columns :/

Comment: @TimRoberts maybe theres a way to use DictReader, then iterate through the keys and some how inject those into the INSERT INTO statement??

Comment: Why not `CREATE TEMP TABLE...`

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano is there a solution where i don't have to list the columns AND am able to manipulate the data?

Comment: Do you know the number of columns? Do you mean 5 cols or rows In your `VALUES` example?

Comment: In order to manipulate the data, you have to use column names.  So, in practical terms, the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to store it in a file (as you don't want to create a table) you can do

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("file::memory:?cache=shared")
```

and to create the temp table (which would be a similar result as `SELECT INTO`), notice that you don't need to specify the column types

```
crt = 'CREATE TEMP TABLE t('
ins = 'INSERT INTO t VALUES('
for n in range(len(csvrows[0])):
    if n:
        crt += ', '
        ins += ', '
    crt += f'c{n}'
    ins += '?'
crt += ');'
ins += ');'
sqlcursor.execute(crt)
sqlcursor.executemany(ins, csvrows)
```

**sqlite** has a `VALUES` keyword that you can use in a `SELECT UNION` or similar, for example

```
sqlite> VALUES (0,1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8,9) UNION SELECT * FROM sqlite_master;
0|1|2|3|4
5|6|7|8|9
```

but I don't think this could help.